# Is it possible to reincarnate as a Upadeva?

Tags: rebirth

There are ten types of [Upadevas](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/compilation/puranic-encyclopaedia/d/doc242082.html): Vidyadhara, Apsara, Yaksha, Rakshasa, Gandharva, Kinnara, Pisaca, Guhyaka, Siddha and Bhuta.

Is it possible to reincarnate as a Upadeva? Or, a human being can only be reincarnated as an embodied creature.

Comment: The Gita says (don't remember the verse) that you can reincarnate as bhutas and pisachas, if you worship them or practice black arts, while present on Earth. The Gita also says, If you worship your pitris or ancestors then you'll reincarnate in the pitrloka. Don't know about yakshas, gandharvas and the rest.